# Restrict CQL filter to a specific BBOX

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, cql-filter, bbox

I need to filter an OpenLayers layer using a CQL filter to an specific Bounding Box. Is it possible?

Something like this isn't working:

```
igh > 5000 AND bbox(igh,20786691,22051867,-305577260,-306370356)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Which mapserver are you running/requesting maps from?

According to [Geoserver CQL Tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html):

> CQL provides a full set of geometric filter capabilities. Say, for example, you want to display only the states that do cross the (-90,40,-60,45) bounding box. The filter will be **BBOX(the_geom, -90, 40, -60, 45)**

Comment: Thanks for your response underdark. It's GeoServer 2.0.2

Comment: Isn't 'igh' some random attribute and not the geometry?

Comment: 'igh' is just a variable associated to the maps

Comment: Have you tried: "igh > 5000 AND bbox(the_geom,20786691,22051867,-305577260,-306370356)"?

Comment: Yes, and the server returns an error to me "blablabla The column 'the_geom' doesn't exist". Thanks again!

Comment: Do you use PostGIS as a data source for that layer? Does the geometry column have a different name there?

Comment: I asked to my technical OGC this morning, and he told me that 'the_geom' is called 'location'. Using it instead of 'the_geom' now works. Thanks underdark! Problem solved

Comment: I've got following geoserver exception while trying to do bbox cql filter: internal error  while evaluating [window SRID does not match layer SRID] operator ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 286. Can you please tell what could be reason of that?

Comment: Do you know how to specify the SRID of the BBOX? New question at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283623/how-to-specify-the-srid-in-a-cql-filter-query-which-includes-bbox - thanks

Comment: It's a good idea to use longitude values above 90 and below -90 in examples so that the order of the coords is obvious at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else figuring out how to use `BBOX AND CQL filter` with ~version `2.10+`. You want to do something like:

/geoserver/eis/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=[layer name]&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&srsName=EPSG:4283&maxFeatures=100&cql_filter=BBOX([GEOM_FIELD]],151.09596,-33.609279,151.336939,-33.479914)%20AND%20status=%27active%27

replace [GEOM_FIELD]

So this was restricting with:

`BBOX(the_geom,151.09596,-33.609279,151.336939,-33.479914)
AND
status='active'`

Hope that helps, the documentation on this is quite terse