# Using CQL_FILTER BBOX on WMS layer causes ORA exception window SRID does not match layer SRID

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, extents, cql-filter

I'm trying to limit WMS layer to a specific BBOX.

```
mainLayer.mergeNewParams({
    'CQL_FILTER' : "BBOX(geom, 6541844, 5577147, 6584851, 5620154)"
});
```

Which gives following exception in geoserver's log:

```
Internal error while evaluating [window SRID does not match layer SRID] operator ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_INDEX_METHOD_10I", line 286.
```

Obviously geoserver hasn't pass SRID information of my BBOX to an oracle sdo filter.
How can I deal with that? Should I edit Geoserver source or is there any Openlayers way to alter "window" SRID in cql_filter query?

Openlayers version: 2.11, Geoserver version: 2.1.2

This question is related with another question: [Restrict CQL filter to an specific BBOX](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/5640/4263)

Comment: are those coordinates in the projection of your map? which WMS version are you using?

Comment: yeah, they're almost the same as the original bbox of the map. WMS is 1.1.1 (or 1.3.0)

Comment: very old post, but do you remember how did you ended up solving this?

Comment: @wired00 unfortunately no :(