# How to specify the SRID in a CQL_FILTER query which includes BBOX?

Tags: geoserver, wfs

Using GeoServer 2.10.1 and WFS, I need to perform a spatial *and* attribute query. According to the [CQL tutorial](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/cql/cql_tutorial.html#geometric-filters) it's necessary to use a CQL_FILTER which contains a BBOX, eg:

`&CQL_FILTER=BBOX(geom,149.81,-34.20,149.83,-34.18) and name = 'ABERCROMBIE RIVER`'

My issue is that I need to specify the SRID in the BBOX query, but I can't see the syntax for this given anywhere.

How can I specify the SRID of the BBOX when it's used in a CQL_FILTER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the [ECQL reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#spatial-predicate) shows that you add it to the end of the parameters.

> BBOX ( Expression , Number , Number , Number , Number [ , CRS ] )
>
> Tests whether a geometry intersects a bounding box specified by its minimum and maximum X and Y values. The optional CRS is a string containing an SRS code (For example,  'EPSG:1234'. The default is to use the CRS of the queried layer)